# Upper bound of norm of matrix difference

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Given matrices $A$ and $B$, I can use the reverse triangle inequality to get a lower bound on the norm of the difference
$$||A|| - ||B|| \leq ||A-B||$$

Is there a way to get an upper bound for the general case or for any special case?

Answer (score 1):

Well, by the ordinary triangle ineq, you have
$$
\| A - B \| = \| A + (-B) \| \le \|A \| + \|-B \| = \|A\| + \| B \|.
$$
The case where $B = -A$ shows that this bound is tight.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I forgot to say that I'm looking for other upper bounds besides the one you mentioned.